# Como obtener el numero de veces que se repite un dato en un arreglo

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

un gusto en saludarlos

Estoy trabajando con arreglos y me gustaria saber una manera de encontrar el numero de veces que se repite un dato, y como mostrar una unicamente el dato.
Por ejemplo, cuantas veces se repite la palabra "Bogota" de la variable *ciudad_municipio_nom*
Y como mostrarla solo una vez.

Esto debido a que estoy trabajando tambien con Chart para mostrar los datos por medio de un grafico de barras y me muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y como estoy usando chart, los parametros que me pide son los labels y la data, acontinuacion el codigo:

```
 const data = {
        labels: ciudades.map(x => x.departamento_nom),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: `${ciudades?.length}`,
                data: ciudades.map(x => x.departamento_nom),
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 3,
                data: [20, 70, 30, 40]
            }]
    }
```

En conclusion, lo que necesito mostrar es el nombre de la ciudad una sola vez y tambien el numero de veces que se repite es ciudad.

El codigo de abajo es un pequeño fragmento de los datos de la siguiente api https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json

```
var datos = [
{
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265685",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "49",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-02-25 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-16 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265686",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "49",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-02-23 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-16 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265687",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "51",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-02-24 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-16 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265688",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "51",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-02-27 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-13 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265689",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "51",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-03-01 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-16 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "2265690",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-03-02 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "11",
        "departamento_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "11001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BOGOTA",
        "edad": "52",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-02-26 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-03-16 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851419",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52227",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "CUMBAL",
        "edad": "24",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-14 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "1",
        "nom_grupo_": "PASTO"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851420",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-11 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52227",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "CUMBAL",
        "edad": "24",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-13 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "1",
        "nom_grupo_": "Por definir"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851421",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52317",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "GUACHUCAL",
        "edad": "33",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-13 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "1",
        "nom_grupo_": "Por definir"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851422",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52378",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "LA CRUZ",
        "edad": "35",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851423",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-13 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52378",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "LA CRUZ",
        "edad": "36",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-13 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851424",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52378",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "LA CRUZ",
        "edad": "33",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851425",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "52",
        "departamento_nom": "NARIÑO",
        "ciudad_municipio": "52378",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "LA CRUZ",
        "edad": "30",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851426",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-09 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "68",
        "departamento_nom": "SANTANDER",
        "ciudad_municipio": "68081",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BARRANCABERMEJA",
        "edad": "38",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-22 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "PCR",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851427",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "68",
        "departamento_nom": "SANTANDER",
        "ciudad_municipio": "68081",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "BARRANCABERMEJA",
        "edad": "37",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-01 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-10 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-22 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "PCR",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851428",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "66",
        "departamento_nom": "RISARALDA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "66170",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "DOSQUEBRADAS",
        "edad": "23",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Relacionado",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-22 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851429",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "15",
        "departamento_nom": "BOYACA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "15810",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "TIPACOQUE",
        "edad": "19",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "F",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-13 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-22 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    },
    {
        "fecha_reporte_web": "2021-01-15 00:00:00",
        "id_de_caso": "1851430",
        "fecha_de_notificaci_n": "2021-01-11 00:00:00",
        "departamento": "66",
        "departamento_nom": "RISARALDA",
        "ciudad_municipio": "66001",
        "ciudad_municipio_nom": "PEREIRA",
        "edad": "27",
        "unidad_medida": "1",
        "sexo": "M",
        "fuente_tipo_contagio": "Comunitaria",
        "ubicacion": "Casa",
        "estado": "Leve",
        "recuperado": "Recuperado",
        "fecha_inicio_sintomas": "2021-01-08 00:00:00",
        "fecha_diagnostico": "2021-01-12 00:00:00",
        "fecha_recuperado": "2021-01-26 00:00:00",
        "tipo_recuperacion": "Tiempo",
        "per_etn_": "6"
    }
]
```

Agradezco sus comentarios y ayuda.

Comment: Hay algo que no queda claro. Dices *estoy trabajando con Chart para mostrar los datos por medio de un grafico de barras* y ¿muestras un gráfico circular?

Comment: Puedes usar una función [reductora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) sobre tu Array de datos. ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes que hacer muchos gráficos y al parecer no sabes mucho de javascript, te recomiendo usar [alasql](https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql), permite hacer consultas a un array en lenguaje SQL. E incluso si no sabes SQL, puede que su sintaxis te sea más fácil de adecuar a tus necesidades.

Te dejo un ejemplo

```js
function consultar()
{
    fetch("https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json")
        .then(r =>r.json())
        .then(r=> { graficar(r); });

}
function graficar(datos){
  var query = alasql('SELECT ciudad_municipio_nom as muni, COUNT(*) AS cant FROM ? GROUP BY ciudad_municipio_nom', [datos] );

 const config = {
     type: 'bar',
    
     data: {

        labels: query.map(a=>a.muni),
        datasets: [{
            data: query.map(a => a.cant),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
        }]
     },
     options: {
         plugins: {
             legend: {
                display: false,
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: 8,
                    }
                }
            },
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: 10,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   };

    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, config);
}

consultar();
```

```css
#myChart{
    max-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@2"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-ElRFoEQdI5Ht6kZvyzXhYG9NqjtkmlkfYk0wr6wHxU9JEHakS7UJZNeml5ALk+8IKlU6jDgMabC3vkumRokgJA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un modo simple si tu sabes los nombres de las ciudades es con el método filter() y con lenght sabes la cantidad de veces que se repitio :

```
   const ciudadFiltrada = ciudad.filter(elem => elem == "Bogota");
   const cantidad = ciudadFiltrada.length;
```

Si no sabes que ciudades tiene el array puedes usar el siguiente ejemplo para que te devuelva un array de 2 dimensiones donde en la fila obtienes la ciudad y en la columna la cantidad de veces repetida:

```
const ciudades = ["Bogota", "Antioquia", "Cartagena", "Tolima", "Valle", "Cordoba", "Santander", "Cartagena","Bogota","Bogota","Valle", "Santander", "Santander"];
let ciudadesFiltrado = [];
let total = 0;
while(ciudades.length>0){
    let m = ciudadesFiltrado.push([ciudades[0],1]);
    total = 0;
    for(let n = 0; n<ciudades.length; n++){
        if(ciudadesFiltrado[m-1][0] == ciudades[n]){
            ciudades.splice(n,1);
            n--;
            total++;
        }  
    }
    ciudadesFiltrado[m-1][1] = total;
}
console.log(ciudadesFiltrado, ciudades);
```