# En contrar elementos repetidos en un array list javaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber como buscar y mostrar por pantalla elemetos repetidos en un arreglo.

Por ejemplo, cuantas veces se repite "BOGOTA" en la variable "departamento_nom" en esta API : https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json

Y como buscar y mostrar una solo una vez ese palabra, por ejemplo que me muestre una sola vez Bogota, una sola vez Nariño y asi sucesivamente con todo el arreglo

Acontinuacion mi codigo:

```js
const inicialUrl = "https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json";
const fetchApi = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(inicialUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data.length);

  let unic = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.departamento_nom))];
  let ndvr = [];
  var contador = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i].departamento_nom === data[i].departamento_nom) {
      console.log("La ciudad " + data[i].departamento_nom + " se repite " + data[i])
    }
  }

  console.log(unic);
  console.log(ndvr);
};

fetchApi();
```

Lo que quiero imprimir seria algo como lo siguiente:

La ciudad NORTE SANTANDER se repite 8 veces

La ciudad NARIÑO se repite 4 veces

Comment: En qué se diferencia esta pregunta, con la otra que hiciste ayer https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/567834/301324 ??'

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168678/como-encontrar-repetidos-en-un-array-javascript

Comment: Que no encontre respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: No querías hacer un gráfico de barras a partir de un array, teniendo que agrupar la ciudades, cuyo array viene de un json?????

Answer (score 2):

Con un objeto puede contabilizar cuantas veces se repite cada ciudad

```
const ciudades = [
  { departamento_nom: 'NY' },
  { departamento_nom: 'Chicago' },
  { departamento_nom: 'NY' },
  { departamento_nom: 'NY' },
  { departamento_nom: 'Chicago' },
  { departamento_nom: 'Medellin' },
]

// itera la respuesta del API para encontrar la cantidad de veces
// que se repite
const res = ciudades.reduce((acc, next, index) => {  
  return {
    ...acc,
    [next.departamento_nom]: (acc[next.departamento_nom] || 0) + 1
  }
}, {})

// itera los valores de cada objecto para obtener el nombre y cantidad de veces que se repite
Object.keys(res).map((name) => {
  console.log(`La ciudad de ${name} se repite ${res[name]}`)
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, me ayuda mucho.

Comment: Con gusto. Puedes marcar la pregunta como correcta si te funciono

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva, coloque una variable global, que va acumulando, todo mediante un `Objet.values` y un  `forEach`

```js
 const inicialUrl = "https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json";
  const fetchApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(inicialUrl);
    const data = await response.json();

    var global = [];

    Object.values(data).forEach(function ({ departamento_nom }) {
      if (!this[departamento_nom]) {
        this[departamento_nom] = {
          est: departamento_nom,
          inf: 0
        };
        global.push(this[departamento_nom]);
      }
      // porcentaje individual
      this[departamento_nom].inf += 1;
    }, Object.create(null));

    console.log(global);
  };
  fetchApi();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, me ayuda mucho.

Comment: @BrayanJiménez  lo modifique para ver si te sirve